Why does converting a nested python dictionary into a pandas dataframe result in "has no attribute 'items' error?
I have a nested dictionary stored in the variable nested_dict_variable.
The dictionary is retrieved by using SPSS valueLabels Property (Python)
type(nested_dict_variable) results in dict.
print(nested_dict_variable) results in {0: {1.0: '1 - low', 2.0: '2', 3.0: '3', 4.0: '4', 5.0: '5 - high', 99.0: "99 - don't know"}, 1: {0.0: '0 - no', 1.0: '1 - yes'}, 2: {1.0: '1 - A', 2.0: '2 - B', 3.0: '3 - C'}}
I am trying to convert this nested dictionary into a pandas DataFrame, but receive the following error. I don't understand why this attribute error is raised given that nested_dict_variable is (or seems to be) a dictionary!?
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\mypythonfile.py:38
     36 data_list = []
     37 for outer_key, inner_dict in nested_dict_variable.items():
---> 38     for inner_key, value in inner_dict.items():
     39         data_list.append({'Outer Key': outer_key, 'Inner Key': inner_key, 'Value': value})
     41 df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)

AttributeError: 'ValueLabel' object has no attribute 'items'

Here is my code:
# see: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/28.0.0?topic=programs-running-spss-statistics-from-external-python-process#d10392e74
import spss
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# read spss-data
file = r"C:\SPSS-SampleData1.sav"
spss.Submit(
    f"""
GET FILE='{file}'.
"""
)

var_index = []
nested_dict_variable= {}

# initialise the handling of spss commands
spss.StartDataStep()

# access active dataset (the one that was read above)
datasetObj = spss.Dataset()

# get a list of variable objects
varListObj = datasetObj.varlist
for var in varListObj:
    var_index.append(var.index)
    nested_dict_variable[var.index] = var.valueLabels


spss.EndDataStep()


##### CREATE DATAFRAMES #####

# convert nested dictionary to Pandas DataFrame
data_list = []
for outer_key, inner_dict in nested_dict_variable.items():
    for inner_key, value in inner_dict.items():
        data_list.append({'Outer Key': outer_key, 'Inner Key': inner_key, 'Value': value})

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)



# end spss process
spss.StopSPSS()


What is the output of type(nested_dict_variable)?

type(nested_dict_variable) gives me dict

It's difficult to reproduce you issue without a [mre] of nested_dict_variable, but if you really have a dict type, then you should have an items attribute.

Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Please post the working example and the example that causes the error both as plain text.  Also please post the full error traceback, not just the final line.

@JohnGordon thanks for your feedback. i have added the full code as non-working example and the full error message i receive. i also tried to improve the question/description.

@mozway thanks for your feedback. is it possible that even if dict is returned, to not have a dict type?

var.valueLabels might look like a dict, but it's not a dict. It just has a poorly-designed __repr__ implementation that makes it look like one.

You've inspected the type of nested_dict_variable, but nested_dict_variable isn't where the error came from. The error happened when you tried to access inner_dict.items, not nested_dict_variable.items.

Like user2357112 has pointed out, the var.valueLabels looks like a dict, but it isn't one.
I had a quick look in the documentation of this python spss package and it says:

You can iterate through the set of value labels for a variable using
the data property, as in:
varObj = datasetObj.varlist['origin']
for val, valLab in varObj.valueLabels.data.iteritems():
   print val, valLab


So you could try rewriting your code:
data_list = []
for outer_key, inner_dict in nested_dict_variable.items():
    for inner_key, value in inner_dict.data.iteritems():
        data_list.append({'Outer Key': outer_key, 'Inner Key': inner_key, 'Value': value})

I haven't tried it though. Good luck! ;)

thanks a lot. I had to change inner_dict.data.iteritems() to inner_dict.data.items() because apparantly iteritems() was removed in python3 (which is used with SPSS28) and was replaced with items.
